# is it possible to connect web app via azure to my existing sql server 2008 currently installed in my server computer?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

im getting `Server Error in '/' Application.`
after publishing my MVC web app http://crave2.azurewebsites.net/ which is connected to SQL SERVER 2008 R2 at some server? tried adding or removing the suggested code but still doesnt give me any helpful errors, what is usually wrong with this one?

Comment: Can you provide some details about the error you are getting? you need to modify the web.config to see the error . <system.web>
        <customErrors mode="Off"/>
    </system.web>  . Just don't forget to change it back afterwards because this is a security risk

Comment: but is the program possible to run when your sql server database is in different location?

Comment: WRN: Assembly binding logging is turned OFF.
To enable assembly bind failure logging, set the registry value [HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Fusion!EnableLog] (DWORD) to 1.
Note: There is some performance penalty associated with assembly bind failure logging.
To turn this feature off, remove the registry value [HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Fusion!EnableLog].

Comment: it also has this error

Comment: Source Error: 


An application error occurred on the server. The current custom error settings for this application prevent the details of the application error from being viewed remotely (for security reasons). It could, however, be viewed by browsers running on the local server machine.

Comment: change your web.config file to have customErrors mode="Off" so that you can see the error details

Comment: it only shows server error code 500, nothing more

Comment: Could you attach the new error screen shot?